# Inverse of conformal map is conformal

Tags: complex-analysis

I haven't taken complex analysis for some time and have been reading a textbook regarding the Riemann mapping theorem. I stumbled across the comment, that the inverse of a conformal map is also conformal, which I don't know how to prove right now. Maybe I am overseeing something/missing a theorem. The definition of a conformal map I know is the following.

Let $f: H \to G$, then $f$ is called conformal, if $f$ is bijective and meromorphic.
Edit: $H$ and $G$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are $H$ and $G$? If they are both the Riemann sphere, then you have a Mobius transformation, and the result follows.  There are different, nonequivalent definitions in the literature.  I always think of conformal as meaning angle preserving.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Thank you for your Comment. I edited the question accordingly. What bothers me is that the author states that it's a basic result, and doesn't give a proof, but since I haven't figured it out myself I am kind of frustrated. Either it is in fact not basic or I just don't see it.